# Error accessing Google Tagmanager account: (404) Not found or permission denied

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-tag-manager

I started research Google Tag Manager API and use php language to call API function to list all containers with accountId:

```
$containers = $service->listAccountsContainers('accountId');
```

but get error as below:

```
Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/tagmanager/v1/accounts/accountId/containers: (404) Not found or permission denied
```

Otherwise, I've tested on https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/api/v1/reference/accounts/containers/list and get response successfully: `200 OK`.

P/s: I've set service account name, .p12 file, scopes and got access_token return.

Comment: did you give the service account access to the google tagmanager account?

Comment: Please show me more detail - step by step how to give service account access to the google tag manager? @DalmTo

Comment: Thanks so much @DaImTo..I access your post http://www.daimto.com/google_service_account_php/ and fixed it. I missed add service account name into Google Tag Manager. (Administration > Account User Management). Tks so much again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A service account by default does not have access to any Google Tag Manager accounts.   If you want it to be able to access your  account you need to grant it access to the account.

Go to the admin section of Google tagmanager

[image]

Go to user management

[image]

click add new user

[image]

Take the service account email address and use this in the email field of the form above.

Comment: When I do this, the service account gets invited to GTM, but then how do I accept the invitation on behalf of the service account?

Comment: So it will just stay as "invited" but not approved in the GTM user list?